# How to create sub partition in already interval partitioned table in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

I have a table which is interval partitioned on date column. I want to sub partition on these already created partition into list partitioning.

How can I do this in Oracle?

Suppose there is a table in which there exists a date column and a region column along with the other columns.

Table is already interval partitioned with this date column.

Now I want these interval partition to sub partition on the basis on the region column.

How will it be possible?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're on 19c, you can use `alter table` to change the partitioning strategy (this was added in 18c). This allows you to define subpartitions:

```
create table t (
  c1 date, c2 int
) partition by range ( c1 )
  interval ( interval '1' month ) (
    partition p0 values less than ( date'2022-03-01' )
  );
  
insert into t 
with rws as (
  select level x from dual
  connect by level <= 60
)
  select date'2022-03-01' + x, mod ( x, 3 ) from rws;
commit;

select partition_name, subpartition_name, high_value
from   user_tab_subpartitions
where  table_name = 'T';

no rows selected
  
alter table t
  modify partition by range ( c1 )
  interval ( interval '1' month )
  subpartition by list ( c2 )
  subpartition template (
    subpartition p1 values ( 1 ),
    subpartition p2 values ( 2 ),
    subpartition pdef values ( default )
  ) (
    partition p0 values less than ( date'2022-03-01' )
  )
  online ;
    
select partition_name, subpartition_name, high_value
from   user_tab_subpartitions
where  table_name = 'T';

PARTITION_NAME  SUBPARTITION_NA HIGH_VALUE    
--------------- --------------- -------------
P0              P0_P1           1            
P0              P0_P2           2            
P0              P0_PDEF         default      
SYS_P42745      SYS_SUBP42742   1            
SYS_P42745      SYS_SUBP42743   2            
SYS_P42745      SYS_SUBP42744   default      
SYS_P42749      SYS_SUBP42746   1            
SYS_P42749      SYS_SUBP42747   2            
SYS_P42749      SYS_SUBP42748   default
```

Note that interval or auto-list subpartitioning is **not** supported. You'll need to update the subpartition template to add new values as needed.

Comment: Thanks Chris , Can the sub partition (p1 and p2 and pdef ) be further partitioned as well? Like if We want to sub partition (p1 and p2 and pdef) based on another column in two different partition, can we do this?

Comment: You mean sub-sub-partitions? No - you can only have two levels of partitions

Comment: Ok Thanks a lot but Oracle should provide multi lever sub partitioning though. It can help  a lot.

Comment: How exactly would this help?

Comment: How can I drop the sub-partition template ?